# Gmail API: "Invalid Label" When Trying to Set Message Label to One That I Created

Tags: python, gmail-api

I created a label, "handler_gmail", in Gmail's web interface via the typical approach.

When I try to set that label for a message via the Gmail API (Python client library), I get the response HttpError 400, returned "Invalid label: handler_gmail".

I am sure the label exists (I've checked multiple times – no typos).

I am trying to set it like so:

`gs.users().messages().modify(userId=username, id=m['id'], body={"addLabelIds": ['handler_gmail']}).execute()`

I tried adding a `"removeLabelIds": []` key/value pair to the dictionary (thinking maybe it was required), but got the same "Invalid label" error.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated! So close to being able to do what I need to with this project!

Comment: You need to use *ids* not names.

Answer (score 26):

As others have pointed out, you have to use label ids, not label names. I solved this by using the gmail API's [sample code](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python#step_3_set_up_the_sample) and modifying it to print out ids in addition to names:

```
results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
labels = results.get('labels', [])

if not labels:
    print('No labels found.')
else:
  print('Labels:')
  for label in labels:
    print(label['name']+ " "+label['id'])
```

So once you get the corresponding id, your code should look something like:

```
gs.users().messages().modify(userId=username, id=m['id'], body={"addLabelIds":     
['Label_1']}).execute()
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to list the system and user labels via print(gs.users().labels().list(userId=username).execute())

This revealed that the label ID for my label was something else ("Label_1" -- the name was "handler_gmail"). So I will make a support method that gets me a label ID by name, and add the label to the message (via modify) using the ID.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I implemented a parser to change my label names to ID

```
def ModifyMessage(service, user_id, msg_id, msg_labels):
    """Modify the Labels on the given Message.

    Args:
        service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
        user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
        can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
        msg_id: The id of the message required.
        msg_labels: The change in labels.

    Returns:
        Modified message, containing updated labelIds, id and threadId.
    """
    try:
        message = service.users().messages().modify(userId=user_id, id=msg_id,
                                            body=msg_labels).execute()

        label_ids = message['labelIds']

        print('Message ID: %s - With Label IDs %s' % (msg_id, label_ids))
        return message
    except errors.HttpError, error:
        print( 'An error occurred(modify): %s' % error)

def GetLabelIds(service, labels_in):
    result = []
    results = service.users().labels().list(userId='me').execute()
    labels = results.get('labels', [])

    for label_in in labels_in:
        for label in labels:
            if label['name'] == label_in:
                result.append(label['id'])
                break
    return result
```

Now i call the label Creator thus:

```
def CreateMsgLabels(service):
    """Create object to update labels.

    Returns:
        A label update object.
    """
    removeLabels = GetLabelIds(service, ['OLDLABEL'])
    addLabels = GetLabelIds(service, ['NEWLABEL'])
    return {'removeLabelIds': removeLabels, 'addLabelIds': addLabels}
```

My call in my main code looks like this

```
ModifyMessage(service, 'me', id, CreateMsgLabels(service))
```